# Ampersand in file path for Rscript.exe

Tags: windows, r, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run an R script through a batch file that I have written. I want the batch script to be flexible so that I can move it to other computers or have it run off of the network drive and it will work in all cases. What I do is collect the path of the file where the batch file is opened from, and then use that path to activate the R script.

It works fine when I have a file path with no special characters, but I have run into a problem with special characters.

Here is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_SCRIPT_DRIVE=%~d0"
set "_SCRIPT_PATH=%~p0"
set "PATH=!_SCRIPT_DRIVE!!_SCRIPT_PATH!"
```

This seems to work as desired, as when I do

```
ECHO !PATH!
```

I get my desired output of

```
C:\\A&B\File
```

However, when I later go on to run this through Rscript.exe command, it doesn't recognize the delayed expansion and executes the ampersand as a special character. The input of:

```
"!PATH!\R-3.0.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "!PATH!Scripts\Test.R"
```

Returns:

```
'C:\\A' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I only have this problem, though, when I try and run Rscript.exe. I am perfectly capable of opening a file such as

```
"!PATH!Scripts\Test.R"
```

And it executes without any problems. Has anyone else run into this problem before? Does anyone see any problems with my syntax?

EDIT: SOLVED

For anyone who stumbles upon this post in the future, I managed to find a solution to this problem. It turns out that it wasn't a batch script error at all but rather a problem with Rscript.exe, I'm not sure what was going on. Instead of using the Rscript.exe located directly in `\bin`, you must go one step further and use `"!PATH!\R-3.0.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"` which works, most likely because I am running on a 32 bit machine rather than a 64.

Comment: you should a) remove the  `&`  from path **or** b) use another script language (VBS, Powershell).

Comment: Note that in the code shown there is no reason to use delayed expansion. You can just use ordinary `%...%` substitution.

Answer (score 1):

With batch files, you can get this to work usually by escaping the `&` with a `^`.  I do not have a windows machine, but can you first check manually if this works, and if so, I can work with you if necessary to implement a function that does string escaping.

For the substitution one of the two below shoule work ( forgive me as I have not Windows machine ),

```
set workable_filename=%file_name:^&=^^&%
set workable_filename=%file_name:&=^&%
@REM:: I cannot test, but one of these should work
```

Comment: I understand that I can escape the special characters with a ^, but the ampersand is in the middle of my path and I am reading in the variable each time. The only way to get around that would be to run a substitution loop in the path variable each time I run to replace each instance of "&" with "^&", but I am having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: Ok cool :) As long as you are willing to do that.  Lemme get you a loop.  One sec.

Comment: Cool, I updated the path.  I know urls are not recommended, but this has been up since my days of working with DOS over four years ago, so it's probably not going anywhere: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ran into this loop earlier in my search and found that I still could not get it to work. When I did set path=%path:&=^&%  it still didn't work though. The path just remained the same. I had the same problem when I assigned "&" and "^&" to variables before the replace command.

Comment: Did you try the double escape above? `^&:^^&`  Wish I had a Windows machine so I could help more >.<

Comment: Okay, so it would be `^&=^^^&` but for some reason the expansion is still not delayed so that's why it isn't working, but I thought I'd update in case anyone else runs into the same problem

EDIT: The path is `PATH=!PATH:^&=^^^&!` which works to substitute `^&` for all instances of `&`, but this still doesn't solve my problem with expansion occurring too early on the Rscript.exe line

Comment: how about `set some_other_var=!PATH:^&=^^^&!`, then run `!some_other_var!Scripts\Test.R`?